# Object order in StackLayout (Kivy)

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I have a

```
layout = StackLayout()
```

now I put buttons like this

```
for x in range(9): # range() explanation: http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/
            bt = Button(text=' ', font_size=200, width=200, height=200, size_hint=(None, None), id=str(x+1))
            bt.bind(on_release=self.btn_pressed)
            layout.add_widget(bt)
```

the problem is that when I go through layout.children array and show the ids they come in order `9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1` which is reversed and not what I want. How do I get them in proper order? (Reversing the array is not a solution)

Another example

I have:

```
        self.layout = StackLayout()
        bt = Button(text='1', font_size=200, width=200, height=200, size_hint=(None, None), id="1")
        bt1 = Button(text='2', font_size=200, width=200, height=200, size_hint=(None, None), id="2")
        bt2 = Button(text='3', font_size=200, width=200, height=200, size_hint=(None, None), id="3")
        bt3 = Button(text='4', font_size=200, width=200, height=200, size_hint=(None, None), id="4")
        bt4 = Button(text='5', font_size=200, width=200, height=200, size_hint=(None, None), id="5")
        bt5 = Button(text='6', font_size=200, width=200, height=200, size_hint=(None, None), id="6")
        self.layout.add_widget(bt, 1)
        self.layout.add_widget(bt1, 2)
        self.layout.add_widget(bt2, 3)
        self.layout.add_widget(bt3, 4)
        self.layout.add_widget(bt4, 5)
        self.layout.add_widget(bt5, 6)
```

And this shows me this: [image]

Comment: why do you care about its being reversed?

Comment: it makes total sense that you write and read from 0 to X, why reversed, lol?

Comment: i really dont know why it matters to you

Comment: I want to add widgets and than access them with some kind of identifier (int or string)

Comment: then ad widget and access them. try writing some code and show us where it fails

Comment: layout.children[x].id = x, I am trying to achieve that x and id are the same

Comment: Edited question

Answer (score 2):

Kivy reverses the order here for reasons to do with internal dispatching order. It doesn't have to, but it's a design decision.

However, this really doesn't matter at all. If you want to store your objects in some particular structure, do that yourself.

Comment: Of course, I could solve this by creating own array or reversing the children array. But how did you take that design decision, I mean come on, I haven't seen this anywhere else, yet.

Comment: You could mention this at least in the docu and put some best practices, I do not know... but does not seem correct, though this is not fatal exception...

Comment: You know that this also exhausts memory at some point, right? But does not matter, python is not memory friendly anyway...

Comment: The order of a list is irrelevant to the amount of memory used.

Comment: The reason for this ordering is that for some things it's necessary to iterate through the children in reverse order of addition. Whoever designed this thought the convenience of reversing at addition time was the best choice. I'm not sure it was the best decision, but I also really don't thing it's remotely important, it's completely trivial to do what you want and you rarely need to manually iterate through the children anyway.

Answer (score 0):

a possible trick would be:

```
y = 10

for x in range(y):
        bt = Button(text=' ', font_size=200, width=200, height=200, size_hint=(None, None), id=str(y-x))
        bt.bind(on_release=self.btn_pressed)
        layout.add_widget(bt)
```

Comment: Why do I need tricks when this should be a standard? Come on I see this first time in Python especially Kivy... isnt there a normal ordered array, why is the children array reversed?

Comment: should I setup orientation?

Comment: possibly.
Valid orientations are ‘lr-tb’, ‘tb-lr’, ‘rl-tb’, ‘tb-rl’, ‘lr-bt’, ‘bt-lr’, ‘rl-bt’ and ‘bt-rl’.

Comment: yes but this is just for front placing, not about the array itself. The array itself is reversed of what is actually shown to the user? **Kivy, really?**

Comment: check the answer by the creator of kivy posted right now

Comment: @LimoTuz Last In First Out is quite common, it's not strange. Also if you get more into Kivy, you'l be glad the order is like that. It's quicker.